# Like button throwing error in chrome

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

We've integrated a like button into the site.
Sample page:
www.2knowb440.com/agent/sergey-koltunov

How ever is I try to like a page A popup opens and closes right away.
In the console an error logged:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.2knowb440.com/agent/sergey-koltunov from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%23cb%3Df2efa6a644%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.2knowb440.com%252Ff1675ba004%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.2knowb440.com%2Fagent%2Fsergey-koltunov&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&send=true&show_faces=false&width=150. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Apparently, chrome is blocking bunch of cookies by default. It basically means that if the user didn't changes these settings he can't work with the site fully. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Shurik

I viewed the public source of your page and see you are loading alot of javascript files before starting facebook's javascript sdk.

Try loading and initializing Facebook just below the < body > tag.

If error persists i would suggest using the i-frame version of the like button with out send.

Comment: I did try it. And the same happening... As I posted in the comment to my own post, the reason for all of it is that chrome blocks some cookies by default. Once I disabled these blocks everything start working...

Comment: By the way, the same problem with google+ button... So, it seems like it's not facebook specific issue.

Comment: Ahh, ya i tried on chrome and portable chrome with no errors.  Perhaps it is a plugin you have installed to chrome.

Comment: Really??? hmmm. All I have is YAGBE, Skype, Gist and Alexa installed and on the other computer the same but without Skype... Also, tried on Mac and windows...

Comment: Well, at least that in not broken for everybody...  :)